# Get the complement of the result of an ls command

Tags: shell, files, ls, wildcards, xargs

Let's say I have a directory with multiple files, all of which are either binary files (files with no declared extensions) and source files (`.c` extension). I do this:

`$ ls`

and get:

`README.md      hello-world.c    hello-world   get-name.c get-name`

and I want to list only files with a specific extensions (say both `.c` and `.md`), I do:

`ls *.c *.md`

and that's ok!

But what if now I want to delete all files that **do not** have a `.c` or `.md` extension, how can I do this?

I know how to do it to files whose extensions are known to me, like:

`ls *.c *.md | xargs rm`

But how do I tell the command line to delete the files that **DON'T** match my criteria?

Comment: Check this one. Hope it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659516/using-find-deleting-all-files-directories-in-linux-except-any-one

Answer (score 6):

Use `find`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 ! -name "*.c" -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

Note that `-maxdepth`, `-print0`, `-r` and `-0` are found in a few `find` implementations (were introduced by GNU `find`/`xargs`) but are not specified by POSIX. Another way is, as Stéphane mentioned in his comment, using the `-exec` action of find - remember to use the `-exec command {} +` form, as it dramatically reduces the number of invocations of `command` (it has to allow syntax where the filenames are placed at the end though, or else you need to wrap the `command` inside a `sh -c` call).

Alternatively `grep` the output of `ls`

```
ls | grep -v "\.c$" | xargs ...
```

You can filter several extensions either with regular expressions:

```
... | grep -v "\.\(c\|md\)$" | ...
```

with extended regexps:

```
... | grep -Ev "\.(c|md)$" | ...
```

with fixed strings option (won't match just at the end of filename!):

```
... | grep -vF ".c
.md" | ...
```

or by chaining more `grep`s:

```
... | grep -v "\.c$" | grep -v "\.md$" | ...
```

That said, `find` is probably the best option, since with the `-print0` option it handles all possible characters in filenames that might need escaping otherwise (provided your `find` and `xargs` are able to work with NULL-terminated strings - e.g. the GNU tools are).

Comment: The find version is the only one that will work with all filenames, but it won't work in all versions of `find` and `xargs`. The `-not` is GNU find only.

Comment: In most cases, you can replace xargs with the `-exec` flag of `find`. Note that `find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '*.c'` returns `.`, you may want to add `-mindepth 1`, or use the standard form: `find . ! -name . -prune ! -name '*.c' ! -name '*.md' -exec rm -f {} +`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas actually `-type f` is probably better in this case, since `rm -f {} +` will fail with a directory argument.

Comment: Then, that would be `! -type d`. `-type f` is for _regular_ files only.

Answer (score 5):

In `ksh`, you can use:

```
rm -- !(*.c|*.md)
```

Those globbing extensions are also available in `bash` after `shopt -s extglob` and in `zsh` after `setopt kshglob`.

The following is the zsh native equivalent:

```
setopt extended_glob
rm -- ^(*.c|*.md)
```

The `!` in an extglob is "not". For your original command, it's preferred to write this:

```
rm -- *.c *.md
```

Parsing the output of `ls` is unreliable, and will break on some filenames. See the bash wiki for [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Hmm, does not work on ZSH :/

Comment: @rodrigoalvesvieira updated for zsh